# Connect to Bluetooth speaker at user login with systemd?

Tags: fedora, systemd, bluetooth

I have Bluetooth speakers which I would like to automatically connect to when I log in to my desktop computer. What is a reliable way to accomplish this on Fedora Workstation 33 please?

I can manually connect to the speakers using GNOME's bluetooth settings GUI or execute `bluetoothctl connect C8:84:47:XX:XX:XX` in terminal (with my true MAC address, redacted here). The bluetooth speakers are AC powered and have power-saving features disabled - they are always on and ready to connect.

A systemd user service seems to be one option, however I can't get this method to work yet. Here's what I have tried so far.

I have a file ~/.config/systemd/user/bluetooth-soundbar.service with the following contents:

```
[Unit]
Description=Connect to soundbar at login

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=bluetoothctl connect C8:84:47:XX:XX:XX

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

I enabled and started the new service with `systemctl --user enable bluetooth-soundbar.service && systemctl --user start bluetooth-soundbar.service`

I tried adding BindsTo=bluetooth.service and/or After=bluetooth.target to the [Unit] section [as recommended in the documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html), however these do not appear to have any effect. I also tried with ExecStart=/bin/sh -c "bluetoothctl connect C8:84:47:XX:XX:XX" (instead of using the command by itself).

/etc/bluetooth/main.conf has AutoEnable=true by default, and `systemctl status bluetooth` shows bluetooth running automatically and by default after login.

The Arch wiki mentions adding "load-module module-switch-on-connect" to /etc/pulse/default.pa, however when I tried this I had no sound or sound settings after rebooting so reverted to the default file.

What am I missing please? Can this be accomplished, and is systemd the correct tool for something like this?

Answer (score 2):

A [user on another forum posted the solution](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/t/connect-to-bluetooth-speaker-at-login/12147/2).

Here it is, for completeness:

Add a .desktop file in the autostart directory...

```
$EDITOR ~/.config/autostart/bluetooth-soundbar.desktop
```

...with the following contents, adapted for your device's MAC.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Bluetooth Soundbar
Exec=bluetoothctl connect C8:84:47:XX:XX:XX
Type=Application
```